# Placeholder API downloading but not registering

Tags: plugins, minecraft

I'm desperate. I try to install an extension for pAPI, and it downloads alright, but never registers. NO PLUGIN REGISTERS. The only 2 that do work are the ones that I have installed very early on for Scoreboard-Revision (Scoreboard plugin). These plugins are Player and Server, and I can unregister them, register them again, and so on. But for some reason, no other plugins want to register. Here's a photo:

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P61US.png)

Answer (score 0):

Some expansions of PlaceholderAPI Require a Plugin to be installed, make sure you have installed the required plugin so the expansion can work.

*Information taken from the [PlaceholderAPI Wiki F.A.Q](https://github.com/PlaceholderAPI/PlaceholderAPI/wiki/FAQ#plugin-is-enabled)*